# GPO/cmd to Powershell

Tags: powershell, gpo

I'm on the search to get a GPO command to a Powershell command

I cant find a way to phrase it to powershell

i got this gpo command

```
Powercfg -setDCValueIndex 2a737441-1930-4402-8d77-b2bebba308a3 48e6b7a6-50f5-4782-a5d4-53bb8f07e226 0
```

this works on the gpo but can i make this to work with a powershell script, i tried it with `powercfg -change`but i work wrong with it or it isnt possible this way

do i have to make a gpo object in powershell ?
like this

```
New-GPO -Name "MyGPO" | New-GPLink -target "to change" -LinkEnabled Yes"
```

if yes this is the only thing i found so far
in this case i try to change the usb selective suspend off for both instances
the other code would only change DC to AC so well yeah

i know the GUID for the subgroup and the GUID for the setting but how to work with this in powershell script

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround

you can run

```
powercfg /SETACVALUEINDEX SCHEME_CURRENT 2a737441-1930-4402-8d77-b2bebba308a3 48e6b7a6-50f5-4782-a5d4-53bb8f07e226 0
```

and

```
powercfg /SETDCVALUEINDEX SCHEME_CURRENT 2a737441-1930-4402-8d77-b2bebba308a3 48e6b7a6-50f5-4782-a5d4-53bb8f07e226 0
```

so you have disabled those options you can run this as batchfile as well